# PHP - echo JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Hello** everyone !
I'm working on a board based on bootstrap, i've got a database filled with sounds informations (name / genre / link soundcloud ...)

In my PHP page, I echo a button which call a JS function with a PHP argument inside.

```
echo "<button onclick='SCM.queue({title:'".$name[$j]."',url:'".$liensc[$j]."'});'>Click me</button>";
```

My problem is, when I look at the source code of my page, I'm supposed to have something like :

```
<button onclick="SCM.queue({title:'Marvin Gaye - Sexual Healing (Kygo Remix)',url:'http://soundcloud.com/kygo/marvin-gaye-sexual-healing'});">Click me</button>
```

But instead i've got :

```
<button onclick="SCM.queue({title:" marvin="" gaye="" -="" sexual="" healing="" (kygo="" remix)',url:'http:="" soundcloud.com="" kygo="" marvin-gaye-sexual-healing'});'="">Click me</button>
```

So, I'm looking for the right synthax :)

Hope someone can help me !
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You quote improperly

Try this

```
echo "<button onclick='SCM.queue({title:\"".$name[$j]."\",url:\"".$liensc[$j]."\"});'>Click me</button>";
```

https://eval.in/139055

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
echo '<button onclick="SCM.queue({title:\''.$name[$j].'\',url:\''.$liensc[$j].'\'});">Click me</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo "<button onclick=\"SCM.queue({title:'".$name[$j]."',url:'".$liensc[$j]."'});\">Click me</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<button onclick=\"SCM.queue({title:'".$name[$j]."',url:'".$liensc[$j]."'});\">Click me</button>";
```

[Example](https://eval.in/139056)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 echo "<button onclick='SCM.queue({title:'{$name[$j]}',url:'{$liensc[$j]}'});'>Click me</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I isolate the code like so:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <pre>
  <?php
    $name[1] = 'Marvin Gaye - Sexual Healing (Kygo Remix)';
    $liensc[1] = 'http://soundcloud.com/kygo/marvin-gaye-sexual-healing';
    $j = 1;

    $line = "SCM.queue({title:'".$name[$j]."',url:'".$liensc[$j]."'});";
    echo $line . "\n";

    echo "<button onclick='SCM.queue({title:'".$name[$j]."',url:'".$liensc[$j]."'});'>Click me</button>";

  ?>
  </pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

$line and the button show as:

```
SCM.queue({title:'Marvin Gaye - Sexual Healing (Kygo Remix)',url:'http://soundcloud.com/kygo/marvin-gaye-sexual-healing'});
```

**Which means your syntax is correct.**

I'm wondering if you've somehow managed to enter the line you provided in this example correctly but it is different to the one you're using in your real app! 
It may also be worth checking that the $name[] variable is indeed passing normal string data.

Normally, I'd make sure that something in the onclick='' part is a variable as it makes it simpler to read because you're not getting as lost in nested single and double quotes.

eg:

```
$onclick = "SCM.queue({title:'" . $name[$j] . "',url:'" . $liensc[$j] . "'});";
echo "<button onclick='$onclick'>Click me</button>";
```

Several of the other answers have suggested escaping the quotes out (with a \") which is good, but its probably still better to not have it inline in the echo statement, unless you're really sure of understanding what you're trying to do!

Edit:
Also see: https://eval.in/139090

for an exapmple